# Xcode Simulator For iPad app displays zoomed in like and iPhone app

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

[image: Screen Shot of iPad Simulator Screen]

I created a brand new Xcode project using the master detail template. Just running the project off the bat my Xcode simulator runs all iPad devices in the below format.

It looks like an iPhone app is being ran on an iPad. In the bottom right corner there is a 1x button. When clicked it turns into a 2x button.

I've reset all device and settings in the simulator and changed the project to run on on other iPad devices but still having the issue. Again this is an out of the box project with no adjustments made. Ive attached a screenshot of what it looks like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you check this setting in the "general" tab in your project build settings is set to iPad instead of iPhone?

[image]

Comment: Im kicking myself for not seeing that. The current device was set to iPhone. This solved my questions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help, figured that's what it was as I've been there myself. ;)